# not looping through all the data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a script to get data within the html element there is a div with an id ticker and I wanted to get all the data within the divs present in the ticker div I am only getting the first one in my console log not getting the rest of them please can anyone help me out

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $("#ticker");
var calls = [];
table.each(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('div'),
    url = $tds.eq(0).text(),
    Company_name = $tds.eq(1).text(),
    open = $tds.eq(2).text();
    high = $tds.eq(3).text();
    var row_id = (i + 1);   
    console.log(url);
}); 
});
```

This is my html

```
<div id="ticker" style="height:18px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:3px;width:6000px;">


<div style="width:180px;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <font color="#f6c644">tag 1</font>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;52.24&nbsp;/&nbsp;1.33M&nbsp;
    <font color="#4eff00">&nbsp;0.16</font>
    </div> 
    <div style="width:180px;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <font color="#f6c644">tag 2</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;93.5&nbsp;/&nbsp;1.07M&nbsp;
    <font color="#4eff00">&nbsp;1.4</font>
    </div> 
    <div style="width:180px;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <font color="#f6c644">tag 3</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;74.2&nbsp;/&nbsp;0.84M&nbsp;
    <font color="#ff0000">&nbsp;-0.47</font>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly similar to [jQuery: Loop print only one value](//stackoverflow.com/q/43108120). Iterating over `$("#ticker")` where it should be `$("#ticker div")`

Comment: now i am geting empty and on console.log on riht hand side numeric value as 3

Comment: @MarkAlan make 2 changes 1) ``$("#ticker div");`` and 2) ``var $tds = $(i)``,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var table = $("#ticker");
var calls = [];
table.find('div').each(function(i,item) {
    var $tds = $(this);
    var url = $tds.eq(0).text();
    var Company_name = $tds.eq(1).text();
    var open = $tds.eq(2).text();
    var high = $tds.eq(3).text();
    var row_id = (i + 1);   
    console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ticker" style="height:18px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:3px;width:6000px;">


<div style="width:180px;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <font color="#f6c644">tag 1</font>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;52.24&nbsp;/&nbsp;1.33M&nbsp;
    <font color="#4eff00">&nbsp;0.16</font>
    </div> 
    <div style="width:180px;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <font color="#f6c644">tag 2</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;93.5&nbsp;/&nbsp;1.07M&nbsp;
    <font color="#4eff00">&nbsp;1.4</font>
    </div> 
    <div style="width:180px;float:left;text-align:center;">
    <font color="#f6c644">tag 3</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;74.2&nbsp;/&nbsp;0.84M&nbsp;
    <font color="#ff0000">&nbsp;-0.47</font>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `each` needs to find every `div` initially its looping only on `ticker` once